# Creating Conditional Fields in Event Forms

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, profile, forms, condition

The Profile Conditionals Extension is great for developers, however, we have clients that want to be able to add conditional fields in forms "on the fly", without having to come to us each time to add to civicrm.settings.php.

Is there a way to do this, or a workaround?

Does anyone know if there are plans to incorporate this UI functionality into Civi?

We are currently using Joomla 3.10.8, Civi 5.48.2.
Thank you!

Comment: If there is any hope of this coming in core civi then it will probably involve SearchKit so you might want to do some background reading on that.

Comment: will do thank you!